# apache .htaccess redirect with modrewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need some help making a redirect for a request like `123.456.789.10/x/y/...`
to a certain domain hosted on the same server lets say `domain.com/x/y/...`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 123\.456\.789\.10
RewriteRule ^x/y/ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: But I still have problems with urls like 123.456.789/x/y/asdf/ghj

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get past this too?

Comment: That's odd. You didn't add a `$` in `^x/y/`, right? That could cause it. If not, try to add `Options -Multiviews` before the RewriteCond.

Comment: That didn't help. Any other sugestion ;) ?

Comment: Apart from Multiviews I don't see any reason why it would ignore the rest of the path. Try in a different browser in case your browser is caching the 301 redirect—frequent problem.

Comment: 123.456.789 is not a proper IP address. Was that just a typo that you left off the .10? You might want to try surrounding your IP address with ^ and $ to see if it makes any difference (force an exact match). Otherwise, it could well be a caching issue.

Comment: Simon, what Phil means is that in your example `123.456.789/x/y/asdf/ghj` there is no `10`

Comment: The wrong IP addres was just a typo. It was actualy a caching problem. After I cleared the cache everything works like a charm. Tnx everybody

Comment: Glad it worked, Simon. I know it was an old rule, but FYI when you make a new rule, it's a good idea to start with `R`, then only do `R=301` when you sure it's working. This prevents caching problems. :)

Comment: Is it possible not to change url in the client browser when doing the redirect? The web site is on the same server and i would like to only do an internal redirect. In the client browser i would like to show the original request url 123.456.789.10/x/y/asdf/ghij.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You want to replace `R=301` with `P`, but this will only work if `mod-proxy` is enabled.